# Exchange 5.6.0 Error - bounce backs contain e-mail addresses who were never meant to receive the e-mails

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm having a bit of an odd issue with one of my Exchange servers.

**The Exchange Environment is as follows**

- Exchange 2010 is primary mail server (CAS, HT, MB roles installed)
- Exchange 2003 is still around service public folder functionality / will catch any e-mails in case primary server is down
- Exchange 2003 has mail filtering from Vamsoft ORF
- Primary Exchange uses Exchange Server Toolbox for spam filtering
- We have a secondary MX pointed to our ISP's server in the event both of the other servers go down

I've had at least two people e-mail me with 5.6.0 NDR's (*The e-mail system had a problem processing this message. It won't try to deliver this message again.*) with a particular account in use (I'll call them User 1). The issue is that e-mail accounts seem to be affected that had nothing to do with the e-mails at all.

**Instance One**

A user gets an NDR from the Exchange Server stating that the message could not be delivered to User 1 because the system had a problem processing it (5.6.0). The weird thing here is that user did not e-mail User 1, nor was their e-mail address included in the conversation at all. The user is not a delegate for User 1.

**Instance Two**

A different user get's an NDR while trying to e-mail User 1, stating that the e-mail could not be delivered to two addresses that were not involved in the e-mail at all again. Once of the e-mail addresses was internal, the other was external. The server logs show no indication that the different user's account, or User 1's account tried to e-mail either of the accounts that NDR's were issued for.

Scouring through Google has left me without answers. If anyone knows what might be going on I would really appreciate the help. The only commonality between the two cases is User 1 being involved.

SAMPLE NDR (Instance 2)

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

external-person@externalorg.com
The e-mail system had a problem processing this message. It won't try to deliver this message again.

Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: externalorg.com

external-person@externalorg.com
#< #5.6.0 smtp;554-5.6.0 Corrupt message content 554 5.6.0 STOREDRV.Deliver.Exception:ConversionFailedException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Content conversion: Corrupt summary TNEF content. ConversionFailedException: Content conversion: Corrupt summary TNEF content.> #SMTP#

Original message headers:

Received: from externalorg.com (10.240.187.152) by
 mailserver.externalorg.com (10.240.187.175) with Microsoft SMTP Server
 id 14.1.218.12; Mon, 22 Apr 2013 10:24:05 -0400
Received: from externalorg.com (127.0.0.1) id hel40a0171sv for
 <external-persona@externalorg.com>; Mon, 22 Apr 2013 10:24:05 -0400
 (envelope-from <sending-user@internal.com>)
Received: from SGCHC-VM1 ([10.240.187.155]) by externalorg.com (SonicWALL
 7.3.3.5225)    with SMTP; Mon, 22 Apr 2013 10:24:05 -0400
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Envelope-From: internal-non-recipient@internal.com
Return-Path: <internal-non-recipient@internal.com>
Received: from mailserver.internal.com (mailserver.internal.com [XX.XX.XX.XX] (may
 be forged))    by mailserver.externalorg.com (8.13.6/8.13.1) with ESMTP id
 r3MEKXSZ022398 for <external-person@externalorg.com>; Mon, 22 Apr 2013 10:20:40
 -0400
X-Process: ESTProcessDone
Received: from mailserver.internal.com ([::1]) by mailserver.internal.com ([::1])
 with mapi id 14.02.0328.009; Mon, 22 Apr 2013 10:20:12 -0400
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
From: Andrew Lee <alee@hscorp.ca>
To: Intended Recipient <intended-recipient@internal.com>
CC: CC'd Recipient <cc-recipient1@internal.com>, CC'd Recipient 2 <cc-recipient2@internal.com>
Subject: E-mail Subject
Thread-Topic: E-mail Subject
Thread-Index: Ac4/ZHxWtkrvSmNBRGqAJRSzwwi+UA==
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2013 10:20:12 -0400
Message-ID: <F6BCE004A6B0DB4091C1BD9C1EC31438013DFAAE@mailserver.internal.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <F6BCE004A6B0DB4091C1BD9C1EC31438013DFAAE@mailserver.internal.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Originating-IP: [10.0.12.245]
X-CSC: 0
X-CHA: v=2.0 cv=erhoOPVX c=1 sm=1 a=k0VIoRiYxUMh6u6gEgVkiA==:17
    a=x53dPfel6-oA:10 a=xqWC_Br6kY4A:10 a=WD2BLewFzigA:10 a=yMhMjlubAAAA:8
    a=SSmOFEACAAAA:8 a=M0gbf96hAAAA:8 a=-6-XvkMfAAAA:8 a=NDS3pNQkAAAA:8
    a=roYoVj6sLU96OE0orLQA:9 a=yPGI6Zi_0VQA:10 a=UiCQ7L4-1S4A:10
    a=hTZeC7Yk6K0A:10 a=frz4AuCg-hUA:10 a=tXsnliwV7b4A:10 a=8hAFxE-LPOcA:10
    a=fU_8NNzUAV1fr42A:21 a=k0VIoRiYxUMh6u6gEgVkiA==:117
X-WHL: SLR
X-Mlf-KeyWords: assignments,research
X-Mlf-Language-Detected: NoLanguageFilter_english
X-Mlf-Connecting-IP: XX.XX.XX.XX
X-Mlf-Country-Code: CA
X-Mlf-Threat: nothreat
X-Mlf-Threat-Detailed: nothreat;none;none;none
X-Mlf-UniqueId: i201304221424050009667
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is no longer present after updating the anti-spam software (Exchange Server Toolbox) to the newest version. We have tested this for well over a month and no recurring issues have presented themselves